# Custom Metrics not working | Google Analytics

Tags: java, android, google-analytics, google-analytics-firebase

Here is my Java file that defines my tracker :

```
    package com.example.anantchowdhary.simpletodo;

import android.app.Application;
import android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo;

import com.google.android.gms.analytics.GoogleAnalytics;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.HitBuilders;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Logger;
import com.google.android.gms.analytics.Tracker;

/**
 * Created by anantchowdhary on 18/09/16.
 */
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    public Tracker mTracker;
    public void startTracking()
    {

            if(mTracker==null)
            {
                GoogleAnalytics ga = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);

                mTracker = ga.newTracker(R.xml.track_app);

                ga.enableAutoActivityReports(this);

                //ga.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);


// Send the custom dimension value with a screen view.
// Note that the value only needs to be sent once.
                mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder()
                        .setCustomMetric(1, 5)
                        .build()
                );
            }

    }

    public Tracker getTracker()
    {


           startTracking();

            return mTracker;

    }

}
```

The MainActivity file is :

```
package com.example.anantchowdhary.simpletodo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;




import com.example.anantchowdhary.simpletodo.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity

{


    private ArrayList<String> items;
    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemsAdapter;
    private ListView lvItems;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // ADD HERE
        lvItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvItems);
        items = new ArrayList<String>();
        itemsAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
        lvItems.setAdapter(itemsAdapter);
        items.add("First Item");
        items.add("Second Item");

        ((MyApplication)getApplication()).getTracker();

    }

    public void onAddItem(View v) {
        EditText etNewItem = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etNewItem);
        String itemText = etNewItem.getText().toString();

        items.add(etNewItem.getText().toString());
        etNewItem.setText("");
    }
}
```

Now I do know that hits are passing on to Google Analytics, since I can see active users(1) in my Real Time Analytics Dashboard on GA. And this is as soon as I enter the app.

However, my custom metric ( with index 1) still displays 0.

Would really appreciate help with this !

Comment: @Brais Gabin Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

A few things might be happening:

1. You're not passing the custom metric to Google Analytics
2. You're passing it but you have a configuration issue that's
   filtering it out

Try using the Google Analytics Tag Recording tool to record a session on your site and see if the custom metric is being passed to Google Analytics, to help figure out where your problem is.

[Quick training video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_7zoJR6uq2g)

[Get Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tag-assistant-by-google/kejbdjndbnbjgmefkgdddjlbokphdefk?hl=en)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Will the chrome extension somehow help with tracking requests from Android ?